# How to take SAS query for SUM(Case) and make them work in Teradata SQL

Tags: sas, teradata, teradata-sql-assistant

I am trying to run a query that was built in SAS and not getting the case statements to work in Teradata SQL

Original SAS CODE

```
CREATE TABLE WORK.RSL_Validation AS 
SELECT 
t.eventDt, 
t.repID,
t.validation1,
t.validation2,
t.validation3,

(SUM((
CASE
WHEN t.validation1 is missing
THEN 0 
ELSE 1
END), 
(CASE
WHEN t.validation2 is missing 
THEN 0
ELSE 1 
END), 
(CASE
WHEN t.validation3 is missing 
THEN 0 
ELSE 1
END))) AS Val_Count
FROM RSL t;
```

The values for validation1, validtion2 and validation3 show up as '?' in the table I made however they would be null I suppose.

SQL CODE I am trying is:

```
CREATE TABLE WORK.RSL_Validation AS 
SELECT 
t.eventDt, 
t.repID,
t.validation1,
t.validation2,
t.validation3,

SUM((
CASE
WHEN t.validation1 is null
THEN 0 
ELSE 1
END), 
(CASE
WHEN t.validation2 is null
THEN 0
ELSE 1 
END), 
(CASE
WHEN t.validation3 is null 
THEN 0 
ELSE 1
END))) AS Val_Count
FROM RSL t;)
WITH DATA ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS;
```

Nothing seems to work

Comment: Are you trying to sum the three values independently on each row? Or generate an aggregate across all of the rows? I don't thing Teradata has a `SUM(a,b,c)` function. Try just using addition,`a+b+c`. If you are trying to aggregate then Teradata will not remerge aggregate values like PROC SQL will.  Every variable selected needs to be either part of the GROUP BY or an aggregate function.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to CROSS JOIN the original table with an aggregate sub-select. If you want the count over DATE you need to INNER JOIN to a grouped aggregate sub-select. Per @Tom, a simple plus (`+`) operator can be used to add individual column aggregates together.

Example:

Presume each date group has 10 rows.  So each date has 30 potential validations.

```
data have;
  call streaminit(123);
  do date = today()-10 to today();
    do repid = 1 to 10;
      array val val1-val3;
      do over val;
        val = ifn(rand('uniform') < 0.20, ., rand('integer',1,10));
      end;
      output;
    end;
  end;
  format date yymmdd10.;
run;

proc sql;
  create table want as
  select
    have.date
  , repid
  , val1
  , val2
  , val3
  , val1_val3_DATE_N
  , val1_val3_ALL_N
  from
    have
  cross join
    /* AGGREGATE OVER ALL ROWS SUBSELECT */
    (select 
        sum (case when val1 is missing then 0 else 1 end) 
      + sum (case when val2 is missing then 0 else 1 end) 
      + sum (case when val3 is missing then 0 else 1 end) 
      AS 
        val1_val3_ALL_N
     from have
    ) as COMPUTE_ALL_N
  join
    /* DATE GROUPED AGGREGATE SUBSELECT */
    (select
      date
      ,
        sum (case when val1 is missing then 0 else 1 end) 
      + sum (case when val2 is missing then 0 else 1 end) 
      + sum (case when val3 is missing then 0 else 1 end) 
      AS 
        val1_val3_DATE_N
     from have
     group by date
    ) as COMPUTE_DATE_N
  on
    have.date = compute_date_n.date   /* INNER JOIN CRITERIA */
;
```